# What's wrong with my calculation of Variance?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, variance

Given $X_i$ ~ $Uni(0, 0.5)$ and $N$ ~ $Poisson(24)$ where $Y=\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i$ I want to cauculate $Var(Y)$.

Here's my approach:

$Var(Y)=E(Y^2)-E(Y)^2$ Where it's given (to make calculations shorter) that $E(Y)=6$ so we get:

$Var(Y)=E(Y^2)-36$

We know that:

$E(Y^2)=E(E(Y^2)|N)$

$E(E(Y^2)|N=n) = n^2/12 + n/6$

So we get:

$E(Y^2)=E(E(Y^2)|N) = E(N^2/12 + N/6) = 600/12 + 4$

So:

$Var(Y)=50+4-36=18$

But the final answer is 2, what did I do wrong here?

Comment: What does $N$ have to do with the other random variables here?

Comment: (I suppose it is the distribution for $n$ but it would be easier to read if you made that explicit).

Comment: You should probably use the *law of total variance*: $Var(Y)=E[Var(Y\mid N)]+Var(E[Y\mid N])$ which here is $E\left(\frac N{48}\right) + Var\left(\frac N4\right) = \frac12+\frac32=2$

Comment: How did you get $E[Y] = 6$?